# Create Docker container with both Java and Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, docker, dockerfile

I am not sure why I expected this to work:

```
 # Dockerfile    
 FROM node:6
 FROM java:8
```

but it doesn't really work - looks like the first command is ignored, and second command works.

Is there a straightforward way to install both Node.js and Java in a Docker container?

Ultimately the problem I am trying to solve is that I am getting an ENOENT error when running Selenium Webdriver -

```
[20:38:50] W/start - Selenium Standalone server encountered an error: Error: spawn java ENOENT
```

And right now I assume it's because Java is not installed in the container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use single `FROM` per generated image.
Try to use `node` as a base image and install java to it.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
```

You can choose the version you need:

```
apt install default-jre
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Comment: yep, I guess, but that means I spend 30+ extra seconds installing java - if it were an image, it would be much faster...

Comment: in some cases, it's taking a minute to install java, no fun

Comment: How to install java in node as a base image

Answer (score 28):

The best way for you is to take java (which is officially deprecated and it suggests you use `openjdk` image) and install node in it.

So, start with

```
FROM openjdk:latest
```

This will use the latest openjdk image, which is `8u151` at this time. Then install `node` and other dependencies you might need:

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

You might want to install things like grunt afterwards, so this might come in handy as well.

```
RUN npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

In total you will get the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh \
RUN npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

You may clone the Dockerfile from my gitlab repo [here](https://gitlab.com/flexbox/docker/java-nodejs)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the latest version of node, which should be 7

Comment: The problem is that this will install a much older version of nodejs on Debian - how can I get a newer version of both npm and nodejs? For nodejs, I use "RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -"

Comment: How about this (another edit)? It installs `npm` as the official github readme suggests. Should be latest version.

Comment: Hi @AlexKarshin, Just let you know, if I use your docker file directly, I get `Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 6: unknown instruction: &&`. If I reformate your code into one line, then it can work properly.

Comment: @Laurence thank you for the tip, I fixed my answer. You should add a backslash to indicate the instruction is not over on that line and that it should continue on the next line.

Comment: The latest version of the `openjdk:latest` image uses Oracle Linux (A Red Hat based distro) as its base, rather than Debian. This means `apt` is no longer available, and `yum` needs to be used instead.

Comment: The latest version, `openjdk:16-jdk-oraclelinux8`, no longer seems to have `yum` unfortunately.

Comment: @MalcolmCrum `openjdk oraclelinux8` images use slim version of `oraclelinux8` which no longer have `yum` nor `dnf` installed. Instead they have `microdnf` which you use the same way (example installing cron from `Dockerfile`): `RUN microdnf update -y && microdnf install -y cron`  https://github.com/oracle/container-images/issues/16#issuecomment-543459881

Comment: That's why you should actually specify versions in code, latest will always change and will not work anymore!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `node` image and then install the `default-jre`:

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
```

You can choose the version you need:

```sh
apt install default-jre
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, you might want to try this https://hub.docker.com/r/timbru31/java-node  one to create the docker file.

This docker image comes with both Java and Node pre-installed. It comes in handy when both are required as a dependency.

Something like,

```
FROM timbru31/java-node:<tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with node v16.15.0, be careful with the packages version of java, I'm using the latest by default. The packages used for java are:

- Java Runtime Environment (jre)
- Java Development Kit (jdk)

```js
    FROM node:16.15.0

    RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install default-jre -y \
     && apt-get install default-jdk -y

    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY package*.json ./

    RUN npm install
    
    RUN npm install --global nodemon

    COPY . .

    EXPOSE 3000

    CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I hope this works for you all

Answer (score 1):

The `FROM` inside your dockerfile simply tells docker from which image it should start the configuration. You can't simply concatenate multiple images together. There are already multiple container images available which offer preinstalled Java 8 and node JS. I don't want to recommend any image specifically but will direct you to [docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=Java+node&starCount=0) for you to go search on your own and use the container that suites your needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
FROM openjdk:16-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 14 of node it works perfectly for me:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh \
RUN npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```