# npm command not available in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I use this:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and then we link nodejs executable to node like so:

```
RUN sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

that's all well and good, but for some reason the "npm" command is not available after installing nodejs.

Why would that be? I thought npm was always bundled with nodejs? What do I need to do to get npm installed too? I am certain that nodejs is installed, but npm does not appear to be present, `$(which npm)` yields nothing.

Comment: Using sudo in docker tends to be a bad practice (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#user)

Comment: Which base image do you use? (FROM ...)

Comment: Hey Vlad, I am using "FROM openjdk:latest"

Comment: LOL by the way, this install Node.js version 0.10, what the heck, Node is on version 7, almost 8

Answer (score 3):

If you are using my solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769730/create-docker-container-with-both-java-and-node-js/43770163#43770163) (and it indeed looks as you do), then you should know, that Java image is [based on Debian Jessie](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/882461ade8207de7647d083009200de85eb978bc/8-jdk/Dockerfile#L7).

If you take a look at Jessie packages, then you will see, that Jessie has `npm` [as a separate package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/web/npm)

Comment: Let's mark this answer as solving the issue :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So as you already mentioned, your docker base image is `openjdk:latest`

No surprise when you run `apt-get install nodejs` it installs version 0.10. Since that's what's available in Debian repos at the time. And as @nordenheim correctly pointed - npm wasn't included into node.js distribution.

So based on your comments looks like you want to install a fresh node.js, like 7.x.

You have 3 options:

1. Base your Dockerfile on `openjdk:latest` + install node.js on your own. Just copy a few lines from official node.js Dockerfile - https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/7.10/wheezy/Dockerfile
2. Base your Dockerfile on `node:latest` + install OpenJDK. Just another way around.
3. Use something already built, like docker image with both openjdk + node - https://hub.docker.com/r/silas/openjdk-node/~/dockerfile/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it might be a documentation bug:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

looks like to install npm along with nodejs, we need to use:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs npm
```

this is

1. a bit surprising (although it's good that npm is now decoupled
   from nodejs)
2. a lot more deps are being installed now, which sucks

Comment: Looks like the `apt-cache depends nodejs` could also answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22112729/2123530. Thanks to you, I learned an new OPS trick today :)

Comment: if you like what you see, give a thumbs up :)